# Unable to get informations of my marker using react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to get some informations about my marker using react and react-leaflet a lib based on leaflet. I thought to use `useRef` but it does not work. Indeed when I try to use `console.log()` to see the properties of my marker I got no informations such as the icon for instance.

Here is the full code :

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";

import "./styles.scss";

const App = () => {
  const markerRef = useRef();

  function getMarkerProperties(marker) {
    console.log(marker);
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer
      className="markercluster-map"
      center={[51.0, 19.0]}
      zoom={4}
      maxZoom={18}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />

      <Marker
        ref={() => {
          console.log(() => getMarkerProperties(markerRef.current));
        }}
        position={[49.8397, 24.0297]}
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you very much for your help !

NB : you can see the full project there : [My project](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-haze-pzmidg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useRef` is used to create a reference to an element or component and that reference is passed to the `ref` attribute of the element.
`useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.
So you should pass the reference to the `ref` attribute of your `Marker` and then you can access the marker with `markerRef.current`.
`import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";`

```
import "./styles.scss";

const App = () =&gt; {
  const markerRef = useRef();

  function getMarkerProperties(marker) {
    console.log(marker);
  }

  return (
    &lt;MapContainer
      className="markercluster-map"
      center={[51.0, 19.0
```